# Mocking/stubbing whether or debug log is enabled?

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

How do I write a mock test that allows me to validate that an inaccessible property (`debugLog`) is set to true? Do I try to find a way to find the value of the property? Do I verify that `console.debug` is set? Does a spy make sense in this situation or should I use a stub?

Class X

```
let showDebugLogs = false,
debugLog = _.noop

/**
 * Configures Class X instances to output or not output debug logs.
 * @param {Boolean} state The state.
 */
exports.showDebugLogs = function (state) {
    showDebugLogs = state;
    debugLog = showDebugLogs ? console.debug || console.log : _.noop;
};
```

Unit Test

```
    describe('showDebugLogs(state)', function () {
        let spy;
        it('should configure RealtimeEvents instances to output or not output debug logs', function () {
            spy = sinon.spy(X, 'debugLog');
            X.showDebugLogs(true);
            assert.strictEqual(spy.calledOnce, true, 'Debug logging was not enabled as expected.');
            spy.restore();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mock testing is used for "isoloting" a class under test from its environment to decrease its side effects and to increase its test-ability. For example, if you are testing a class which makes AJAX calls to a web server, you'd probably do not want to:

```
1) wait for AJAX calls to complete (waste of time)
2) observe your tests fall apart because of possible networking problems
3) cause data modifications on the server side
```

and so on.

So what you do is to "MOCK" the part of your code, which makes the AJAX call, and depending on your test you either:

```
1) return success and response accompanying a successful request
2) return an error and report the nature of the point of failure to see how your code is handing it.
```

For your case, what you need is just a simple unit test case. You can use introspection techniques to assert internal states of your object, if this is what you really want to. However, this comes with a warning: **it is discouraged**. ***Please see Notes at the bottom***

Unit testing should be done to test behavior or public state of an object. So, you should really NOT care about internals of a class.

Therefore, I suggest you to re-consider what you are trying to test and find a better way of testing it.

Suggestion: Instead of checking a flag in your class, you can mock up logger for your test. And write at least two test cases as follows:

```
1) When showDebugLogs = true, make sure log statement of your mock logger is fired
2) When showDebuLogs = false, log statement of your mock logger is not called.
```

**Notes**: There has been a long debate between two schools of people: a group advocating that private members/methods are implementation details and should **NOT** be tested directly, and another group which opposes this idea:

[Excerpt from a wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development#Best_practices):

> There is some debate among practitioners of TDD, documented in their
>   blogs and other writings, as to whether it is wise to test private
>   methods and data anyway. Some argue that private members are a mere
>   implementation detail that may change, and should be allowed to do so
>   without breaking numbers of tests. Thus it should be sufficient to
>   test any class through its public interface or through its subclass
>   interface, which some languages call the "protected" interface.[29]
>   Others say that crucial aspects of functionality may be implemented in
>   private methods and testing them directly offers advantage of smaller
>   and more direct unit tests